# Laravel 5 Testing Database MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.1

In Laravel 4, I could specify the testing database through the `config/testing/database file`.

This file has, of course, been removed from Laravel 5 just to make things pointlessly more difficult.

So, how do I set up a MySQL test database in Laravel 5.

I do not want to use a SQLite database.

I would suggest some code but there isn't anything on SO or through Google that even attempts to answer this question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the documentation [Testing - Test Environment](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing#test-environment) this mentions you set environment variables in the phpunit.xml

So for example you would add

```
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

to set the `DB_CONNECTION` I know you said you don't want to use SQLite but this is just an example you can set any of the values you would normally set in your `.env` file.

See [Using Environment Variables to Add Flexibility to PHPUnit Tests](http://elnur.pro/using-environment-variables-to-add-flexibility-to-phpunit-tests/) for some more details on the use of environmental variables with PHPUnit.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with the following approach:

Set your default databse connection to 'testing' when the app environment is also 'testing' in your database.php file:

```
    'default' => app()->environment() == "testing" ?
                env('DB_CONNECTION_TESTING', 'testing') :
                env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

Then also in your database.php file add the testing connection:

```
'testing' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST_TESTING', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_TESTING', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME_TESTING', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD_TESTING', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

In your .env file you have to add the corresponding lines:

```
DB_HOST_TESTING=localhost
DB_DATABASE_TESTING=database_testing
DB_USERNAME_TESTING=username_testing
DB_PASSWORD_TESTING=password_testing
```

So every time the app environment is testing ( which is the case in phpunit tests for example ) your application uses the testing database connection.

Of course you could also modify the phpunit.xml file like mentioned in the answer of Mark Davidson.